# Anyway to get dataurl from scaled up 2d context?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas which has a varying height & width according to view-port width. Now the canvas is used to create a final png using toDataURL. But I need the final png at a fixed resolution. So I have to scale up the 2d context from the canvas.. But how to get the dataurl from that scaled up context? I am not going to use a second canvas.

*Ultimate goal is to keep a single canvas(I have limited space for it. e.g-640x480 div container while the png I require is of 1920x1080 res) on which drawing will be done. Then I need a scaled up version of the drawn canvas as png

**UPDATE:**
The content on the canvas were svg and texts, which were scalable. It was shown at a lower resolution. So what I needed was to save the at an enarged frame to get a high resolution output without tampering with the quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the answer. I figure it out myself.

```
canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png',multiplier: 1920/canvas.width});
```

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score -2):

All elements can have a life outside the page, you can create them, use them as you want and then derefernce them for GC to clean up later.

An example using a offscreen canvas to scale an image.

```
// Returns a new Image at size width, height
function resizeImage(image, width, height){
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas"); // create a canvas element
    canvas.width = width;  // set its width and height
    canvas.height = height;
    // Draw the image scaled onto it
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image,0,0,width,height);
    // Create a new image element
    const scaledImage = new Image;
    // Set its src to the canvas content
    scaledImage.src = canvas.toDataURL(); // default mime type image/png
    // Return the new scaled image. 
    return scaledImage; // note Image may no have loaded at this point
    // The canvas is dereferences and will be cleaned up by GC very soon.
    // nobody will ever know it existed ;|
}
```